# Get the code that trigger onReceive of Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

```
class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            doSth();
        }
}
```

In the main activity:

```
Intent intentA = new Intent(MainApplication.getAppContext(), Receiver.class);
Intent intentB = new Intent(MainApplication.getAppContext(), Receiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntentA = PendingIntent
                         .getBroadcast(MainApplication.getAppContext(),0,intentA,0);
PendingIntent pendingIntentB = PendingIntent
                         .getBroadcast(MainApplication.getAppContext(),0,intentB,0);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5000,
                60000, pendingIntentA);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5000,
                60000, pendingIntentB);
```

In the function doSth() i want to know if this broadcast is triggered whether by intentA or intentB, how can i do that without explicitly putting additional information into the intent?, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Because the `Intent`s are exactly the same and because of that, the `PendingIntent`s are also exactly the same. You will need to put something in the `Intent` to differentiate: either the `Intent` ACTION, `Intent` DATA, or some "extras".